# Object.toString() -> [object Object]

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, post, geojson

The following code send by using Ajax a json :

```
var geojson = new Object();
geojson["type"] = "FeatureCollection";
geojson["zone_type"] = "Zone";
$.ajax({
  url : url,
  type : 'POST',
  data : geojson,
  dataType : 'json',
});
```

However, when I ask in the console "geojson" and when I look the request in the network :

```
geojson = "[object Object]"
```

Actually, I should have the object :

```
geojson = {type:FeatureCollection,zone_type:Zone}
```

Shouldn't I ?

Comment: try `data: JSON.stringify(geojson)` and `console.log( "geojson = ", geojson );`

Comment: Well, yes. In the network these are going to be passed as parameters in the POST request. Then in the console you should see the object. Remember you can always do console.log(<something>) in your code and this will output to the console.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem (at least, not without setting `processData: false` which isn't something your [mcve] does. When I add a `url` variable (also missing from your MCVE) and run that code, I get a URL Encoded Form Data body in the POST request. I don't see `[object Object]`. I don't see JSON either. Are you actually trying to send JSON? (In your "answer" you said *However, is it possible to remove " in the result* but that would be invalid for a JSON text). Are you confusing JSON with JavaScript objects?

Comment: You question title says `Object.toString()`, but you don't call that anywhere in the code you supplied. Are you using that? You're getting the expected results for doing that … if you don't want that result, why are you doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var geojson = new Object();
geojson["type"] = "FeatureCollection";
geojson["zone_type"] = "Zone";
$.ajax({
  url : url,
  type : 'POST',
  data : JSON.stringify(geojson),
  dataType : 'json',
});
```

If I add JSON.stringify(geojson) indeed, I get correctly :

```
geojson = {"type":"FeatureCollection","zone_type":"warning_zone"}
```

Thank you very much @SLYcee